# how to call myslot using item click signal in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

Want to trigger "itemClicked" event for a QTreeWidget Item using the following code.

```
connect(aTreeWidget,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),this,SLOT(CallM(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int)));
```

but the CallM slot is not called,don't no what is the problem here !?
there is no syntax or build error, I am using Qt 4.7.1/Win 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to add Q_OBJECT In my class, after adding it works fine

Answer (score 3):

From the `QObject::connect(....)` docs

> the signal and slots parameters must not contain any variable names,
>   only the type.

Remove the 'item' word from the slot arguments.

Comment: Got it, and removed 'item' from arguments, but still not working, think there is some other issue as well !! . .the connect returns always false.

Comment: Check debug outputs. QObject::connect will notify you if it failed

Comment: I missed to add Q_OBJECT In my class, after adding it works fine.

Comment: You should put that in an answer and accept it yourself then.